# Django clean-image-crop-uploader issue

Tags: django, image-uploading

I'm writing a simple blogging site where I'd like to enable the user to upload and crop an image to use it as their post banner.
I've been trying to implement [cicu](https://github.com/asaglimbeni/clean-image-crop-uploader) (clean-image-crop-uploader). Since I'm using Django 1.6 I had to fiddle a little bit with the example that's provided but I managed to get it working flawlessly. However I cannot seem to be able to implement it into my project.

My uploading box seems to duplicate buttons. Also once an image has been uploaded there are 3-4 cropping areas appearing instead of one. (One being a random preview area)
[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Here's my article model

```
class Article(models.Model):
'''Article Model'''

image = models.ImageField(
    verbose_name="image",
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    upload_to='/ajax_uploads/',
    max_length=300
)

title = models.CharField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Title'),
    help_text = _(u' '),
    max_length = 255
)
slug = models.SlugField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Slug'),
    help_text = _(u'Uri identifier.'),
    max_length = 255
)
content_markdown = models.TextField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Content (Markup)'),
    help_text = _(u' '),
)
content_markup = models.TextField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Content (Markup)'),
    help_text = _(u' '),
)
categories = models.ManyToManyField(
    Category,
    verbose_name = _(u'Categories'),
    help_text = _(u' '),
    null = True,
    blank = True
)
date_publish = models.DateTimeField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Publish Date'),
    help_text = _(u' ')
)

class Meta:
    app_label = _(u'blog')
    verbose_name = _(u'Article')
    verbose_name_plural = (u'Articles')
    ordering = ['-date_publish']

def save(self):
    self.content_markup = markdown(self.content_markdown, ['codehilite'])
    super(Article, self).save()

def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title,)


class ImageCrop(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Article
    cicuOptions = {
        'ratioWidth': '', #if image need to have fix-width ratio
        'ratioHeight':'', #if image need to have fix-height ratio
        'sizeWarning': 'False', #if True the crop selection have to respect minimal ratio size defined above.
    }
    widgets = {
        'content_markdown' : PagedownWidget(),
        'image': CicuUploderInput(options=cicuOptions)
    }
    exclude = ['content_markup',]
```

View:

```
@login_required
@never_cache
def new_article(request):

if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...

    form = ImageCrop(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/')

else:
    if request.GET.get('id',None):
        form = ImageCrop(instance=Article.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id',None)))
    else:
        form = ImageCrop()

return render(request, 'blog/article/new_article.html', {
    'form': form,
    })
```

Template:

```
{% block meta %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="{% static "cicu/css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="{% static "cicu/js/bootstrap.js" %}"></script>
{{ form.media }}
<title>CICU Image Crop ajax Uploader</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form id="testFormCicu" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I really cannot tell where exactly it went wrong. I'm really sorry for wasting your time if it's something simple that I missed. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATAE**

It looks like my js/css duplicated the cropping area. I have no idea why and how but when I've stripped that out it worked!

Almost that is... Now it throws 400's when trying to crop anything.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 400 issue is a different problem I'll be answering my own question.

It seems that my js file that handles responsive design duplicated my image cropping field.

Comment: in case anyone wondered... It seems that adding UPLOAD_TO as specified in the example projects settings file to my settings file confused the system. It uploaded the file twice to different directories and refused to crop neither of them.

4:30am here, I should really go to sleep!